# How to add Resources with the same name but different folders in plugin.xml?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a iOS objective-c component which should be included in a PhoneGap/Cordova plugin.

Here is a part of what I have in my plugin.xml file:

```
<platform name="ios">
...

<resource-file src="src/ios/TGCameraViewController/View/Base.lproj/TGCameraAuthorizationViewController.xib" target-dir="TGCameraViewController/View/Base.lproj" />
<resource-file src="src/ios/TGCameraViewController/View/Base.lproj/TGCameraViewController.xib" target-dir="TGCameraViewController/View/Base.lproj" />
<resource-file src="src/ios/TGCameraViewController/View/Base.lproj/TGPhotoViewController.xib" target-dir="TGCameraViewController/View/Base.lproj" />

<resource-file src="src/ios/TGCameraViewController/View/de.lproj/TGCameraAuthorizationViewController.strings" target-dir="TGCameraViewController/View/de.lproj" />
<resource-file src="src/ios/TGCameraViewController/View/de.lproj/TGCameraViewController.strings" target-dir="TGCameraViewController/View/de.lproj" />
<resource-file src="src/ios/TGCameraViewController/View/de.lproj/TGPhotoViewController.strings" target-dir="TGCameraViewController/View/de.lproj" />

<resource-file src="src/ios/TGCameraViewController/View/pt-BR.lproj/TGCameraAuthorizationViewController.strings" target-dir="TGCameraViewController/View/pt-BR.lproj" />
<resource-file src="src/ios/TGCameraViewController/View/pt-BR.lproj/TGCameraViewController.strings" target-dir="TGCameraViewController/View/pt-BR.lproj" />
<resource-file src="src/ios/TGCameraViewController/View/pt-BR.lproj/TGPhotoViewController.strings" target-dir="TGCameraViewController/View/pt-BR.lproj" />

</platform>
```

When I try to add the plugin to my app I get the following error:

```
Failed to install 'org.test.cordova.TestPlugin':Error: Uh oh!
target destination "/Users/mg/Documents/iOS/hello/platforms/ios/HelloWorld/Resources/TGCameraAuthorizationViewController.strings" already exists
    at module.exports.resource-file.install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/ios.js:128:48)
    at Object.ActionStack.process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/action-stack.js:72:25)
    at handleInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:591:20)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:340:28
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
Error: Uh oh!
target destination "/Users/mg/Documents/iOS/hello/platforms/ios/HelloWorld/Resources/TGCameraAuthorizationViewController.strings" already exists
    at module.exports.resource-file.install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/platforms/ios.js:128:48)
    at Object.ActionStack.process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/util/action-stack.js:72:25)
    at handleInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:591:20)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:340:28
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

I tried to use:

```
<framework src="src/ios/TGCameraViewController" custom="true" />
```

This way I can include an entire folder but when I want to make #import "SomeClass.h" it cannot find the file.

**How can I add Resources with the same name but different folders in plugin.xml?**

Answer (score 6):

According to plugin Specification http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification

resource-file element does not support any target attribute. the target attribute is for android its not for iOS.

The solution is simple remove what you have(above code) in your plugin.xml and just keep `<resource-file src="src/ios/TGCameraViewController"/>` in plugin.xml and try to build.

Comment: is it possible to create new folder inside resource folder for IOS? @yaswanthsvist